# Django stops updating data to mysql after page refresh

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

I'm fairly new to using the django framework and recently I made a system with it where it submits data to mysql db through a html form. I got it working eventually and everything seemed quite fine, though I noticed a bug where if I refresh the page django stops sending data to mysql, has this ever happened to anyone?

Stuff for reference:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from websiteDB.models import dbInsert
from django.contrib import messages

def insertToDB(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        if request.POST.get('uname') and request.POST.get('email') and request.POST.get('message'):
            post = dbInsert()
            post.uname = request.POST.get('uname')
            post.email = request.POST.get('email')
            post.message = request.POST.get('message')
            post.save()
            messages.success(request, "Message sent successfully.")
        return render(request, "contact.html")

    else:
        return render(request, "contact.html")
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class dbInsert(models.Model):
    uname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = "contactrequest"
```

**urls.py**

```
"""
websiteDB URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from . import views
from . import index

urlpatterns = [
   #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

   path('homepage', index.page_home, name= 'hpage'),
   path('', views.insertToDB),
   path('contactpage', index.contact_page, name= 'cpage')
]
```

**contact.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/css/styles.css' %}">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(74, 36, 110);">

    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>

    <div class="top-nav">
        <a href="{% url 'hpage' %}">HOME</a>
        <a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a>
        <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
        <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="community.html">COMMUNITY</a>
        </div>

        <div class="div-align">

            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <p>Reach us for questions/concerns through the form below.</p>
        </div>  
    <form class="fontmaker" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="Username">Username:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="Username" name="uname" required><br>
        <label for="E-mail">E-mail:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="Email" name="email" required>
        <label for="Reason" class="margin">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="Reason" name="message" rows="10" cols="60" required>Type your reason of contact here.</textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="rounded-corners" id="submitBtn">

        {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            {{message}}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

There are no errors in terminal, and the button click also properly sends a POST req:
[Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbTWh.png)

I'm also new to posting on stackoverflow, tell me if there's something else to improve on in the future when posting.

**index.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def page_home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def contact_page(request):
    return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, your request always will return the status 200 because this part `return render(request, "contact.html")` isn't inside your if statement

Comment: Ah I see, stupid indentation mistake then I suppose. Thanks for your answer, I'll go see if my issue is fixed.

Comment: Update: Seems like it still didn't update properly to the db

Comment: This will not fix your problem because your problem is your form fields, i strongly suggest you work with django forms to serialize your inputs, it's safer and clean to write code. You are using ajax to send the request?

Comment: No I'm not using ajax, but I'll try looking into django forms.

Comment: Could you share `index.contact_page` view as well?

Comment: In your form tag i don't see action attribute how is it working without it ?

Comment: The inputs have the name attribute, which is how it's called through the py scripts.

Comment: Give your path `path('', views.insertToDB, name='insert_db'),` a name and add `action="{% url 'insert_db' %}"` in the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you render the `contactpage/` URL, then if you submit the form, you will submit it to the `contact` view, but that view does not handle the data, nor does it create any entry. You must make sure that you post the form to the `insertToDB` view. You can do this by giving the view a name:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('', views.insertToDB, name='insertToDB'),
    # …
]
```

and then specify the endpoint in the form:

```
<form class="fontmaker" method="post" action="{% insertToDB %}">
    <!-- … -->
</form>
```

In case of a successful POST request, you should also redirect, for example with:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def insertToDB(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('uname') and request.POST.get('email') and request.POST.get('message'):
            post = dbInsert.objects.create(
                uname = request.POST['uname'],
                email = request.POST['email'],
                message = request.POST['message']
            )
            messages.success(request, 'Message sent successfully.')
            return redirect('cpage')
        return render(request, 'contact.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

I would advise to work with Django [*forms* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/), for example a [*modelform* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) to validate and clean form input and remove a lot of boilerplate code.